# Tracking web traffic on Ubuntu linux

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

One of my employees is spending a lot of time just browsing the web and talking on Google Talk.  I'd like to get a quote of exactly how much time is spent doing these things.  We want to have a lax environment but he's abusing it and I'd like to have some solid information.

He's using Ubuntu Linux, how can I monitor this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), it should be in the default repositories.

Comment: Hrmm... I installed it but I don't see any devices for me to capture.... not even `lo` or `eth0` :-\

Comment: Guess you should run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

writing a script to grep tcpdump for certain keywords would give you an idea.
But for that you would need to run it locally.

Also have you confronted your employee about this?

Comment: It's not actually my employee, I just thought I'd get better results that way.  It's my co-worker that my boss has asked me about his performance.  I'd like to get some facts because I honestly don't pay much attention to what he does cause I'm so focused on my own work.

Comment: IMO you should talk with your employer about your coworker and not try to spy on them, that may reflect badly on you.